# Alter Registration Form Text

Tags: users, forms

I am trying to alter the email description text on my user registration page. I have added the following to the bottom of my template.php file but nothing is happening. It seems like the function isn't even being called. Any suggestions?

```
function theme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    switch($form_id) {
        case 'user_register_form':
            $form['account']['mail']['#description'] = t('E-mail Address');
    }
}
```

Comment: Put this code in module_name_form_alter and use #prefix and #suffix

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the function YOURTHEME_form_alter(), where YOURTHEME  is the name of your theme. Eg, the Bartik theme would have such a function called bartik_form_alter() ... you must also clear your drupal cache for the changes to take affect.

**EDIT**

you make your code like this:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    switch($form_id) {
        case 'user_register_form':
            $form['account']['mail']['#description'] = t('E-mail Address');
    }
}
```

if you call your theme "sky" it would be `sky_form_alter`.

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question. If I want to update the text on the form where could I call it so that it runs and won't be overridden by updates to the modules and drupal itself? Thanks!

Comment: in your theme, like you have ... but call the function the correct name; see my EDIT in the answer.